# Why do I need to eval the lambda in this case

Tags: racket

The following code yieds a `#<procedure>`

```
#lang racket
(require threading)
(~>> 1
     (lambda (x) x)
)
```

I am not sure why this is the case. I need to apply the lambda expression

```
#lang racket
(require threading)
(~>> 1
     ((lambda (x) x))
)
```

only then it yields `1` which is what I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `threading` package provides [`~>>`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._threading%2Fmain..rkt%29._~7e~3e~3e%29%29) as a macro, which inserts the previous expressions into the later expressions. When it sees a pattern like this:

```
#lang racket
(require threading)
(~>> a
     (f b _))
```

It finds the `_` within the second sub-form, and inserts the `a` into that place within the form, `(f b a)`.

What makes it slightly more confusing is that there is a shorthand. If the `_` is at the end of a sub-form in a `~>>`, you can omit it. When it sees something like `(f b)` where there is no `_`, it inserts it at the end, and it is as if you wrote `(f b _)`. This is what happens in the lambda case, it interpreted your syntax as equivalent to `(lambda (x) x _)`.

The result after it inserted the `1` was `(lambda (x) x 1)`. That wasn't what you had expected.

## What you want

From your use of lambda functions and your expectations, it seems as though you don't need this complicated macro behavior; you just want it to apply them as functions. The threading form you want would simply apply the later expressions to the results of the earlier ones, transforming `(~> a (f b))` into `((f b) a)`. This simpler version is provided by the [`point-free`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/point-free/index.html) package as [`~>`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/point-free/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._point-free%2Fmain..rkt%29._thrush%2B%29%29).

```
#lang racket
(require point-free)
(~> 1
    (lambda (x) x))
;=> 1
(~> 1
    (lambda (x) (+ x 10))
    (lambda (x) (expt x 4))
    number->string
    (lambda (x) (printf "~a seconds" x)))
;=outputs> 14641 seconds
```

You can combine this simpler `~>` with a shorthand-lambda package such as `fancy-app` to make expressions like this look nicer.

```
(require fancy-app)
(~> 1
    (+ _ 10)
    (expt _ 4)
    number->string
    (printf "~a seconds" _))
;=outputs> 14641 seconds
```

Comment: This sort of common confusion makes me worry that `threading` is a misfeature, especially since Racket allows such flexible as like `fancy-app`. Do you think it would be worth adding a disclaimer to `threading`’s documentation?

Comment: I think the documentation could be a lot clearer. From the first example it looks like it transfrorms `(~> 1 add1 sqrt)` into `(sqrt (add1 1))`, and then the next example with `bytes-ref` doesn't have much explanation. I'm not sure, How you should introduce the concept that it treats expressions with parentheses differently?

Comment: Well, the whole subsequent section (section 1.2) explains the example with `bytes-ref`. Perhaps that needs to be made more clear? And though it’s briefly mentioned, maybe the point that `f` is equivalent to `(f)` needs to be made more prominent?

Comment: The `f` is equivalent to `(f)` explanation in the beginning doesn't make sense for someone just glancing at the first few examples. You need to make it clear that it treats expressions with parentheses specially within those first two examples.

Comment: That’s fair, yeah. I can try and rewrite some of that documentation when I have some time.